# How to build tess-two (fork of tesseract tools for android)

Tags: android, ocr, tesseract

How to use the this for tesseract I found [here](https://github.com/rmtheis/tess-two)? I am following the readme in that file, but I don't know how to build the project. Specially I am confused where to type this:

```
cd tess
cd tess-two
ndk-build
android update project --path .
ant release
```

I'm not sure if it's gonna work on cmd or do I need something else to build this.

Comment: Type those commands in Terminal(Command prompt). You can refer this tutorial for more info http://gaut.am/making-an-ocr-android-app-using-tesseract/

Comment: i tried to, I was able to reach the directory E:\OCR\tess-two> but when I was about to enter the ndk-build, an error occur saying that 'ndk-build' is not recognized as an internal or external command

Comment: Well you need to install `ndk` first..http://developer.android.com/tools/sdk/ndk/index.html

Comment: can anybody please help me with building a tesserct project in android studio

Comment: You can use Android Studio to do the build, as described here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41154462/building-tess-two-into-a-project-using-android-studios-gradle-build

Answer (score 3):

Here are the steps to build:

- Download the NDK from the Android Development site and extract it to any folder.
- Go to Preferences-->Android -->NDK and select the path for Android-Ndk directory
       ex-->D:\Work\Android\Android Tools\android-ndk-r9
- Import tess-two project. File -> Import -> Existing Projects into workspace -> tess-two directory.
- Right Click on Tess-two--> Properties-->Builders then give any name for Builder like Ndk tess Builder And add location for ndk-build.cmd  ex-->:D:\Work\Android\Android Tools\android-ndk-r9\ndk-build.cmd. select working directory as ${Workspace/tess-two}
- Refresh tess-two, It will take time to build
- After complete build Add it as library:Right click the project, Android Tools -> Fix Project Properties. Right click -> Properties -> Android -> Check Is Library.

Comment: My Android Studio doens't have the preferences->android->ndk and also the right click on tess-two properties isn't available..

Comment: Looks like this one is for eclipse

Comment: Yes this steps is for eclipse.

Answer (score 2):

You can follow these steps to build tess-two library. In case you face any problem, refer http://mindtherobot.com/blog/452/android-beginners-ndk-setup-step-by-step/

- Download and extract android-ndk.
- Download cygwin with devel/gcc-core, devel/gcc-c++, devel/gnu, devel/make packages included.
- Open cygwin command line and open your tess-two lib path in cygwin using cd command eg. cd /cygwin/c/tess-two-master/tess-two .Then use ndk-build command eg. /cygwin/c/android_ndk-09r/ndk-build. The process of building will start. Note that it will take time to build.
- Lastly just import the tess-two libs in eclipse and use it as a library in your project.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to build tess-two. You can do all this stuff without downloading android ndk, cygwin and ant. Just follow this [blog](http://androidtesstwo.blogspot.in/2014/03/making-android-ocr-app-using-tess-two.html) all things are done already for us we just need to download built files.