# Building tess-two into a project using Android Studio's gradle build

Tags: android-ndk, java-native-interface, android-gradle-plugin, android-studio-2.2, tess-two

There are answers about getting the `tess-two` project integrated into an  Android project within *Android Studio*, but many are out-dated and none used the current capabilities defined here:

> Using Android Studio 2.2 and higher, you can use the NDK to compile C and C++ code into a native library and package it into your APK using Gradle, the IDE's integrated build system. Your Java code can then call functions in your native library through the Java Native Interface (JNI)

What specific steps would be required to make `tess-two` functionality a part of the resulting APK, using functionality within *Android Studio*, rather than external file placement, manipulation and command line tools?  So taking the building, creation of *.so files into the IDE.  Specifically using just *Android Studio*'s **integrated build system** (Gradle) as described [here](https://developer.android.com/ndk/guides/index.html).

**1. Start a new project**

[image: starting a new Android Studio project with C++ support]

**2. Import Tess-Two into the project**

[image: import tess-two as a module in the new project]

**2b. Add any needed plug-ins**

[image: add to tess-two build.gradle to pull required plug-ins]

**3. Add code in the main activity to get native functionality**

[image: static import of tess-two native files]

**4. Configure *Android Studio* build so that native functionality is available**

*This is where the specifics are required*

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**4. Configure *Android Studio* build for native functionality**

**4a. Link C++ Project with Gradle**

First, check the `tess-two` project for build files.  You may select CMakeLists.txt or Android.mk files.  Both are currently supported.

[image: checking project build config files]

In this case, I used `ndk-build`, which seemed like a good bet for integrating the native code.

[image: Linking C++ project]

For more information, see [Android Studio documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/projects/add-native-code.html#link-with-ui)

**4b. Manage Long Commands**

In Windows, errors may be encountered if the command length grows too large.  To prevent problems, use `LOCAL_SHORT_COMMANDS` AND `APP_SHORT_COMMANDS` in the `Android.mk` file.

[image: Adding attributes that reduce command length]

The "e=87" error is what you are avoiding by doing this:

[image: The parameter is incorrect error 87 message]

For more on that topic, see [stackoverflow question about error 87](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12598933/ndk-build-createprocess-make-e-87-the-parameter-is-incorrect).

**4c. Add Module Dependency for tess-two**

In *File > Project Structure > Dependencies* use the *+* to add the `tess-two` dependency:

[image: add tess-two as a dependency]

**4d. Build the Project and check .apk file for .so files**

The build, which takes a long time, should complete now.  Validate that the `.apk` file contains the `.so` files, created during the build.  With the `tess-two` libraries in an static initializer, run the project on your Android device:

[image: apk file with tess-two .so files and running test app]